# How to call a non-generic method of a class T from a method of a generic class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reflection, system.reflection

I am new to reflection and dependency injection concepts, and I started to run some code in order to understand better.

I am trying to call a non-generic method of a class T from a method of a generic class that contains a T object.

Consider the following sample code, when I run it I get this:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Void DisplayProperty() is not a
> GenericMethodDefinition. MakeGenericMethod may only be called on a
> method for which MethodBase.IsGenericMethodDefinition is true.

What I am doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
namespace di001
{
    class MyDependency
    {
        private String _property;
        public String Property
        {
           get => _property;
           set => _property = value;
        }
        public void DisplayProperty()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Property);
        }
    }

    class DIClass<T>
    {
        public T obj;
        public void DisplayMessage()
        { 
             MethodInfo method = typeof(T).GetMethod("DisplayProperty");
             MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));
             generic.Invoke(this, null);
        }
        public DIClass(T obj)
        {
            this.obj = obj;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DIClass<MyDependency> x = new DIClass<MyDependency>(new MyDependency());
            x.DisplayMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think with "MakeGenericMethod" is something wrong here.

Comment: I don't think that line is necessary at all, `T` is not generic once constructed, and `method` certainly isn't. You should be able to just do `typeof(T).GetMethod("DisplayProperty").Invoke` I also imagine you want to call `Invoke` with parameters `(obj, null)`

Comment: Can you please try public void DisplayMessage<T>(){}
If this works kindly tell me i will make this an answer

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks, the problem is solved now!

Comment: When you get `typeof(T)`, are getting the type of the generic type that you instantiated `DIClass` with, in this case `MyDependency`. You have a full class definition at that point, with no need to call `MakeGenericType`. Just call `GetMethod("DisplayProperty")` to get the `MethodInfo` and then `Invoke` it. But, `DisplayProperty` is an instance property of `MyDependency` so you'll need an instance of that type

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you have one, follow @charlieface's suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```cs
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));
```

is not necessary at all.

At this point, when actually executing, `T` is not generic since it has been constructed (`T` is the actual type you want). `method` certainly isn't a generic method anyway.

You should be able to just do

```cs
typeof(T).GetMethod("DisplayProperty").Invoke(...
```

---

I also imagine you want to call `Invoke` with parameters `(obj, null)`

Comment: You're probably going to want the use the _null conditional_ operator (`?.`) on the call to `Invoke` in case the method doesn't exist: `typeof(T).GetMethod("DisplayProperty")?.Invoke(...)`

Comment: @Flydog57 That depends on whether you want it to throw or ignore, I will leave that as an exercise for OP